# Use equation and cases for big and numerous equation

Tags: equations, cases, split

I have a system of differential equations I want to write. Some equations are very long and there are numerous.

I wonder if there is a way to split the equations (automaticaly if possible) and to split the system.
And any advide on how handle big systems is welcomed. (write the system is a good/bad idea, a table is better... anything you want)

Here is a prototype of my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{cases}
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma\\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
            \frac{dx}{dt} = \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions/observations:

- Since the system of differential equations looks like it might span more than 1 page, you should not use an `equation` environment. Instead, use either an `align` or `align*` (the latter if you do *not* need equation numbers) environment, along with an `\allowdisplaybreaks` statement.
- It seems pointless to use a `cases` environment if the equations end up spanning 2 or more pages. However, I may be missing something.
- If you have a long expression on the right-hand side, encase it in a `\parbox` directive, as is shown below. That way, you'll get automatic line-breaking, which would appear to be one of your objectives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     \frac{dx}{dt} &= \parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{\raggedright%
     $\nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma + \nu\alpha\beta\gamma$}\\
     \frac{dx}{dt} &= \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
     \frac{dx}{dt} &= \nu\alpha\beta\gamma \\
     \frac{dx}{dt} &= \nu\alpha\beta\gamma
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: * `align` or `align*`with `\allowdisplaybreaks` instead of `equation` ok
* I don't understand the `cases` part
* what do the parameters of `parbox`mean ?
* With this version, we loose the bracket...

Comment: @Mico: Why a `\parbox` for which you have to specify  a width, whereas `aligned  or `multlined` don't require it?

Comment: @Bernard - the OP asked for automatic linebreaking. Inline-style math in a `parbox` will deliver just that, whereas the `aligned` and `multlined` environments will not. The only, and fairly minor, cost of using a `\parbox` is that a width has to be selected. `0.75\textwidth` is obviously merely an example, but it happens to work in the present case. :-)

Comment: @Ccile - What is a curly brace that spans more than one page even supposed to signify? I honestly have no idea. About the `\parbox` ("paragraph box") directive: `[t]` means that top-alignment is requested (the default is centering), and `0.75\texwidth` specifies the desired width.

Comment: Curly brace on 2 pages -> I have no idea too, it was just in case of...
Ok, thanks